# variable scope and referencing

Tags: python, variables, scope, binary-search-tree

Here, I have copied a reference to the "root" to the "temp" variable before performing operation on root variable on a Binary Search Tree.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right

class Solution:
    def insertIntoBST(self, root: Optional[TreeNode], val: int) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        temp = root
        prev_node = None
        while True:
            if not root:
                if prev_node is None:
                    root = TreeNode(val)
                elif val > prev_node.val:
                    prev_node.right = TreeNode(val)
                else:
                    prev_node.left = TreeNode(val)
                break
            elif val > root.val:
                prev_node = root
                root = root.right
            elif val < root.val:
                prev_node = root
                root = root.left
        return temp
```

This approach works for almost all testcases but fails for when root = []

At this point I realized there is something wrong going on with variable scope, so I started debugging and changed my code to as shown below:

```
    def insertIntoBST(self, root: Optional[TreeNode], val: int) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        temp = root
        prev_node = None
        while True:
            if not root:
                if prev_node is None:
                    temp = TreeNode(val)
                elif val > prev_node.val:
                    prev_node.right = TreeNode(val)
                else:
                    prev_node.left = TreeNode(val)
                break
            elif val > root.val:
                prev_node = root
                root = root.right
            elif val < root.val:
                prev_node = root
                root = root.left
        return temp
```

Now, second piece of code works perfectly, but even after debugging it line by line I could not understand what exactly went wrong with my first piece of code. I have a vague idea that it was related to the variable scope, but just can't put my finger on it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33687950/edit) to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I thought the output screenshot would provide more context to my problem, I didn't realize this was a no-no here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only really three lines executed in case `root` is `[]`:

```
temp = root
    ...
    if not root:
        if prev_node is None:
            root = TreeNode(val)
    ...
return temp
```

So, yeah. `temp` is set to `[]`, then `root` is set to a `TreeNode` (which doesn't affect `temp`), then `temp` (which is still `[]`) is returned.

Comment: Hi, I understood that part and hence I could come up with a soln that passed all test cases. But what I'm most confused about is that I always thought the = operator in python just holds the address to the data in RHS of the equation if it already exists in the memory. In above mentioned code, from my understanding, temp acts as a reference(holds address) to the root variable, and going further if root is None and prev_node is none, a new TreeNode with val is created and assigned to root, but at this point temp is not referencing root. Can you help me understand what happened in between. Thanx

Comment: `temp = root` assigns a reference of the object that `root` references to `temp`. So both variables hold a reference to the same object. Then `root = TreeNode` assigns a reference to a `TreeNode` to `root`. Now `root` holds a reference to a `TreeNode`, but `temp` still holds the reference to the list.

Comment: Play around with some code at http://pythontutor.com to visualise this.